# Is it possible to make a dark/light mode button that changes the inner css colors on all pages?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Currently I am practicing doing a light/dark mode button for a website I am building with HTML and CSS. The website is in dark mode initially as you open it. But how can I make it that when a user clicks the "light-mode" button for all pages to become dark/light mode based on what he has set?

I am currently running this method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#light-mode").click(function() {
        $("body").toggleClass("light-mode-bgr");
        $("h1").toggleClass("light-mode-text");
        $(".message-disc p").toggleClass("light-p");
        $("p").toggleClass("light-mode-text");
        $(".img-rad label p.maybe").toggleClass("light-mode-btn");
        $(".buttons button[type='next']").toggleClass("light", "disabled");
        $(".buttons button[type='button']").toggleClass("light-ret");
        $("input[type=radio]:checked+label>p").toggleClass("light-radio");
        $("input[type=text]").toggleClass("light-inp");
        $("input[type=tel]").toggleClass("light-inp");
        $("input[type=num]").toggleClass("light-inp");
        $("input[type=number]").toggleClass("light-inp");
        $("textarea").toggleClass("light-inp");
        console.log("clicked");
    });
});
```

but obviously this is not changing the inner css, its only changing classes with the toggle I am using, and if I refresh the page on light-mode, that style is gone back to the default dark-mode style.

How can I make it so that it fully changes the inner css so that it applies to all pages in my website? If so is it possible with JQuery?

Comment: To switch, add/remove a class on the `<body>` tag then use css, eg `button { color:white; } .darkmode button { color:black; }`  don't change individual elements.

Comment: You seem to have two *separate* questions: 1) how to change inner css  2) how to persist the users options - there's certainly existing questions for both of these.

Comment: to persist the current theme value, you could use local storage and save the value there https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: There are mamy ways to do that. One of the best ways is to use css variables

Comment: As a very (very, *very*) simple demo of the approach with CSS custom properties (or CSS variables): [demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pe1kozb7/](https://jsfiddle.net/pe1kozb7/). Choose better colours though, contrast is important; in Chrome: open the dev console > ctrl+shift+p > type "emulate" and select "emulate prefers-color-scheme: dark" or "emulate prefers-color-scheme: light" to demonstrate the changes. (Firefox can do the same, but I can't remember how right now).

Comment: @DavidThomas thats so cool, its something like that I am looking to do. But I am far too deep with my css code right now will I have to go back to edit everyhting that has a color with variables? I havent used that method of vars before

Comment: @AzizHakberdiev thank you for the suggestion, I will look more into css variables!

Comment: It's a lot easier than you might imagine, since the variables allows for theming of colours, spacing, borders, font-sizing, line-heights, white-space... If you look for Adam Argyle, or Kevin Powell, on YouTube they both cover customisation with custom properties quite a bit: there's some amazing stuff to see.

Comment: @DavidThomas just watched KP's video and its so helpful, idk why I havent thought of looking for videos honestly.. just got too carried away trying to code.. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wodWDIdV9BY and followed the steps, it required me to change a lot of my css into variables:

```
:root {
        --color-purpe: #FFA14A;
        --color-purple-hov: #DE8430;
        --body-bgr: #2B3549;
        --h1-orange: #ffffff;
        --black-labels: #ffffff;
        --bas-orange: #7D63DE;
        --bas-org-hov: #7D63DE;
        --bas-red: #C34437;
        --bas-red-hov: #b03628;
        --disbaled: #a0a0a0;
    }

.lightMode {
    --color-purpe: #7D63DE;
    --color-purple-hov: #7D63DE;
    --body-bgr: #ffffff;
    --h1-orange: #E18127;
    --black-labels: #000000;
    --bas-orange: #FFA14A;
    --bas-org-hov: #DE8430;
    --bas-red: #C34437;
    --bas-red-hov: #b03628;
    --disbaled: #a0a0a0;
}
```

and then I used this function to make it work:

```
let lightMode = localStorage.getItem('lightMode');
const lightModeToggle = document.querySelector('#light-mode');

// check if light mode enabled
// if off turn on
// if on turn off

const enableLightMode = () => {
    document.body.classList.add('lightMode');
    localStorage.setItem('lightMode', 'enabled');
}
const disableLightMode = () => {
    document.body.classList.remove('lightMode');
    localStorage.setItem('lightMode', null);
}

if (lightMode === 'enabled') {
    enableLightMode();
}

lightModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    lightMode = localStorage.getItem('lightMode');
    if (lightMode !== 'enabled') {
        enableLightMode();
        console.log(lightMode);
    } else {
        disableLightMode();
    }
});
```

so when I click the toggle, light mode is applied and changes the `:root` values into the `.lightMode` class values and gives me the result I wanted.

The function also stores the value in `localStorage` so when I refresh the page it doesnt go back to the default "dark mode" style.